# Convert substring through command

Tags: bash, replace, pipe, substring

Basically, how do I make a string substitution in which the substituted string is transformed by an external command?

For example, given the line `5aaecdab287c90c50da70455de03fd1e ./2015/01/26/GOPR0083.MP4`, how to pipe the second part of the line (`./2015/01/26/GOPR0083.MP4`) to command `xargs stat -c %.6Y` and then replace it with the result so that we end up with `5aaecdab287c90c50da70455de03fd1e 1422296624.010000`?

This can be done with a script, however a one-liner would be nice.

Comment: will there always be 2 fields - separated by a space? what's your input source, maybe a file with multiple lines? also is `xargs` and fewer `stat` required or is it OK with 1 `stat` per file?

Comment: @Milag ultimately I want to process a whole file, with each line being of the format above. Yes they are delimited by a space. It should be one stat by line. I want to replace the filename by the timestamp.

Comment: Also the 1st field (the hash) has a fixed length.

Comment: OK. Simple enough, example script to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

hashtime()
{
    while read longhex fname; do
        echo "$longhex $(stat -c %.6Y "$fname")"
    done
}

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo Usage: ${0##*/} infile 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

hashtime < $1

exit 0
```

---

```
# one liner
awk 'BEGIN { args="stat -c %.6Y " } { printf "%s ", $1; cmd=args $2; system(cmd); }' infile
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work. I was hoping for a one liner but it seems I'll have to go with a script. I will mark your answer as accepted unless someone comes up with an elegant one line solution, if you don't mind.

Comment: OK. Found gawk system() and made a one liner.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner using GNU `sed`, which will process the whole file:

```
sed -E "s/([[:xdigit:]]+) +(.*)/stat -c '\1 %.6Y' '\2'/e" file
```

or, using plain bash

```
while read -r hash pathname; do stat -c "$hash %.6Y" "$pathname"; done < file
```

Comment: `sed` with the `e` flag. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

It's typical to use `awk` `sed` `cut` to reformat input. For example:

```
line="5aaecdab287c90c50da70455de03fd1e ./2015/01/26/GOPR0083.MP4"
echo "$line" |
cut -d' ' -f2- | 
xargs stat -c %.6Y
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I recombine the line to contain 2 fields?

Comment: Contain which fields exactly? Please post the output you want to get.

Comment: I posted the sample input and sample output in the example in my initial post.